# Bind null string to combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I'm not sure why this happens
At XAML, I have

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="25"/>
```

At the code behind, I have

```
cb.ItemsSource = new string[] { null, "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };
```

When I load the UI, the combobox has null set. Now if I change it to "Test1", I don't have an option to revert back to null. At the UI, I see "Test1", "Test2" and "Test3". The null string doesn't create a new entry at the combobox. In my case, null is a valid option. If I change null to , it works fine. But I need null to be shown as a valid option. 
Has anyone see this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding to a string array, use an object array.

```
public class DisplayValuePair
    {
        public DisplayValuePair(string d, string v) { this.Display = d; this.Value = v; }
        public string Display { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

and bind the data as

```
cb.ItemsSource = new DisplayValuePair[] { 
                new DisplayValuePair("", null), 
                new DisplayValuePair("Test1", "Test1"), 
                new DisplayValuePair( "Test2", "Test2" ), 
                new DisplayValuePair( "Test3", "Test3" ) };
```

and xaml as

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedValuePath="Value" Width="140" Height="25"/>
```

So, you don't need to substitute any value at the time of load/save.

Comment: I like this solution. This class could even be make generic, i.e. change the type of the "Value" property to a generic type, so you can use it to display strings for all kinds of objects.

Comment: Yeah.. That's a great idea! More generic!

Answer (score 1):

I normally use a String value like "no selection" for user display instead of null.
This avoids the problem you have and is more clearly for the user.

Before sending something to the database I retranslate "no selection" to null.

If I bind to complex items, I also create one representing null.

Usually this "no selection" text is even localized and stored in a resource file, so that it is appropiate for users of different languages.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. For now, I'll use this option although I need to replace the value when loading and when save. Until I get a better way, I can use this hack.

Comment: I you find a better way, please post it here :-)